# How should I prove that $\log(x)$ is continuous on $(0, \infty)$?

Tags: calculus

Assuming the following properties are given:

$\lim_{x \to 1} \log(x) = 0$

$\log(x_1 x_2) = \log(x_1) + \log(x_2)$

I have to use the definition "for all $\epsilon >0$, there exists a $\delta >0$ such that if $|x−x_0|<\delta$ then $|f(x)−f(x_0)|<\epsilon.$

A solution, or a hint to that, would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'd appreciate if you could give some feedback. Did you succeed in using the hint? Do you need further assistance?

Answer (score 4):

**Hint**
The only thing you're allowed to use is continuity at $1$ with value $0$ and the product law. First prove that $\log x - \log x_0 = \log \frac x{x_0}$ as a lemma from the product law. Can you now chose $\delta$ such that
$$|\log x - \log x_0| = \left|\log \frac x{x_0}\right| < \epsilon$$
(Bonus: $\delta$ depends on the convergence rate of $\lim_{x\to1}\log x=0$)

Answer (score 0):

Write $\log{x_1x_2}-\log{x_2}=log{x_1}$. So we have $x_0=x_2$ and $x_1=\dfrac{x}{x_2}$. If we let $x\to x_2, x_1\to1$, so $\log{x}\to 0<\epsilon$